# Jasmine Tests Do Not Run

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

I am trying to set up Jasmine testing on my Angular Application to test a controller.

Controller:

```
    var navigation = angular.module("navigation", []);

navigation.controller("NavigationController", ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.myObject = [];
    $scope.tabs = [
        { title: "Surcharge Index", content: "SurchargeIndex" },
        { title: "Scheduling and Adjustments", content: "Scheduling" },
        { title: "Auto Update Settings", content: "Automation" },
        { title: "Processing Rules", content: "FuelProcessing" },
        { title: "Data Update ", content: "DataUpdate" },

    ];
}]);
```

Test:

```
    describe("NavigationController", function () {
    var scope;
    var controller;

    //beforeEach(module('app'));

    beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $rootScope) {
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        controller = $controller('NavigationController', { '$scope': scope });
        }));

    it("scope is defined", function () {
        expect(scope).toBeDefined();
        //expect(scope.tags[0].title).toBe('Doe Index');
    });

    it("should contain a list of tabs", function () {
        //expect(scope).toBeDefined();
        expect(scope.tags).toContain({ title: 'Doe Index' });
    });

});
```

Neither Jasmine test is ever run.

Test page:

```
Jasmine2.0.0finished in 0.001s
raise exceptions
Ran 0 of 2 specs - run all
0 specs, 0 failures
NavigationController
scope is defined
should contain a list of tabs
```

This is what Jasmine returns.  For some reason none of the tests are being run.

Any suggestions?

Comment: It looks like the test block of code is being run after jasmine does its test execution. No idea why though...

Answer (score 1):

You have to load the module you are testing:

```
beforeEach(module('navigation'));
```

Add that where you have:

```
//beforeEach(module('app'));
```

But uncommented.

Comment: Thanks for the help. While this did not work perfectly it did get me going in the right direction.  I used the following blog post as a model based on your suggestion.  [Simple Unit Test with AngularJS](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2013/06/10/simple-unit-tests-with-angularjs.aspx)

Comment: No problem, glad that i could help. I suggest you answer your own question with the right solution, that way, when others stumble upon the same issue and get here, they will know how to solve it ;)

Answer (score 0):

I used this [OdeToCode](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2013/06/10/simple-unit-tests-with-angularjs.aspx) post as a sample once I realized that I needed to load the module.  My test case now looks like this.

```
describe("myApp", function () {
    beforeEach(module('navigation'));

    describe("NavigationController", function() {
        var scope;
        var controller;

        beforeEach(inject(function($controller, $rootScope) {
            jasmine.addMatchers(customMatcher);
            scope = $rootScope.$new();
            controller = $controller('NavigationController', { '$scope': scope });
        }));

        it("scope is defined", function() {
            expect(scope).toBeDefined();
        });

        it("should contain a list of tabs", function() {
            expect(scope.tabs.length).toBe(5);
        });
    });
)};
```